# MYSQL JPA Connection Giving Wrong username and password

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, maven, jpa

I am trying to connect Postgres and mysql simultaneously in JPA with Ejb following is my persistence.xml and I am deploying the code in wildfly 10

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">




    <persistence-unit name="pl4smsMYSQL-persistence">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>


        <!-- <shared-cache-element>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-element> -->
        <properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newtable" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
<!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> -->


        <!--    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newtable" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister"
                value="false" />

            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="false" />
               <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="50" /> <property 
                name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" /> <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" 
                value="100" /> <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="1" 
                /> <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" /> <property 
                name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE" /> <property 
                name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" 
                /> <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider" 
                /> <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" /> <property 
                name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" 
                /> <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="/ehcache.xml" 
                />
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
            uncomment generate_statistics line to generate cache statistics
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" /> <property 
                name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
        <persistence-unit name="pl4sms-persistence">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>


    <!--    <shared-cache-element>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-element> -->
        <properties>




            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pl4smstest" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister"
                value="false" />

            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="false" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="50" /> <property 
                name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" /> <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" 
                value="100" /> <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="1" 
                /> <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" /> <property 
                name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE" /> <property 
                name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" 
                /> <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider" 
                /> <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" /> <property 
                name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" 
                /> <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="/ehcache.xml" 
                />
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
            uncomment generate_statistics line to generate cache statistics
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" /> <property 
                name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>




</persistence>
```

and this is the pom.xml I am using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomee-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I am able to connect to postgres  , but for mysql its giving wrong username and password error , i tried connecting mysql with commad prompt its get connected with same username and password. I tried removing Postgres connection and connected using only mysql still it gives the same error.
follwing is the error I am getting

```
    Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:336)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:278)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:1289)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:492)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:627)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:599)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:579)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:430)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:737)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:665)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:137)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:302)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:147)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:122)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:313)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:105)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:90)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:312)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: The error commes from an h2db connect and has nothing to do with your tagged databases: `org.h2.Driver`

Answer (score 0):

A better idea will be to [create two datasources](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/DataSource+configuration) in WildFly and then reference them in your persistence.xml files:

```
<persistence-unit name="pl4smsMYSQL-persistence" transaction-type="JTA">
     <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
     ...
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="pl4sms-persistence" transaction-type="JTA">
     <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSqlDS</jta-data-source>
     ...
</persistence-unit>
```

The great majority of your configuration properties then become redundant.

This will also have the benefit that your servers will be independently configured for each environment so you won't need different application builds for test and production.

Note that you can then also remove the driver jars from your application as they are separately deployed to the server.